# What all is required for email from my server to pass through spam filters?

Tags: email, dns, php, postfix, sendmail

I have a serverbeach server with postfix installed.

The hostname is something like
p3204059.pubip.serverbeach.com

The FQDN is specified as NONE for the server itself.

I clicked change ptr record, I entered my ip and set the FQDN to: mysubdomain.mydomain.com
It may not have finished propagating yet. Is the IP hostname the same as the FQDN the same as reverse dns?

I sent an email from php and it said it worked fine but I don't get the email. Should I change my hostname on the machine to mysubdomain.mydomain.com? What other things do I have to do with the DNS to prevent my email from going into the spam folder?

Comment: Not a complete solution, but an added suggestion. Add an SPF record to your domain DNS records.

Comment: Check your php.ini settings. Sending mail via php is not a real test of a mail server. `sendmail` from the command line would give you a better understanding of what is going on.

Comment: Server Fault has a "Canonical Answer" to this category of question. http://serverfault.com/questions/48428/how-to-send-emails-and-avoid-them-being-classified-as-spam

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First the essentials:

1. Read the relevant RFC:s such as [RFC 5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321), and make sure your mails conform to it, Don't leave out any headers such as `Date:` `Subject:` or `From:`, and carefully read the format details of the `From:` field. **Just an email address is not valid anymore.**
2. Double-check that the `From:` address used is a valid address that you can receive mail to.
3. Make PHP send the mail through your local postfix installation and not directly out on the internet or through the web hosting host.
4. Keep DNS entries the same for forward and backwards lookups
   (`mysubdomain.mydomain.com.` should resolve to the IP address that has a PTR record pointing to `mysubdomain.mydomain.com.`).
5. Make the mail server send its HELO (EHLO) with its correct FQDN (`mysubdomain.mydomain.com.`).
6. [Implement](http://www.dkim.org/ietf-dkim.htm#published) [DKIM signing](http://www.dkim.org/) of outgoing emails
7. Avoid hosting that is shared by systems that are frequently hacked.
8. Add your server to [DNSWL.ORG](http://www.dnswl.org/)
9. Publish an [SPF record](http://www.openspf.org/) for your domain that indicate that your server is a legitimate sender host for your domain
10. Avoid "spammy" content :-)
11. look out for 8-bit characters. They need proper encoding in the headers.

After setting that up, you are ready to troubleshoot if mail still doesn't get through:

1. check the postfix mail queue (`mailq`) and logs, such as `/var/log/mail*log` (filename can differ depending on distribution)
2. if mail doesn't leave the server, postfix usually tells you why.
3. if mail does leave the server, the problem is at the recipient side. Check your mail log for the receivers MX status message. It should look like this:

   ```
    2013-11-26T11:04:23.435295+01:00 jamie postfix/smtp[28919]: 415E65E3976: to=<example.rcpt@blaha.com>, relay=hoover.blaha.se[123.45.67.89]:25, delay=0.24, delays=0.2/0.02/0/0.02, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 661D12C0CD)
   ```

Note the "`status=sent`", the `(250` and "`queued as 661D12C0CD`".

`250` is the status code by the receiving MTA, indicating success and that delivery is their responsibility now. If the status code begins with `4` (as in `450`), there was a temporary error and the message should remain in your queue (visible with `mailq`). If the status code begins with `5` (as in `550`), there was a permanent failure, and there is no point in trying again with the same recipient address. Then the mail is removed from your queue and not delivered, and a bounce message might be sent back to the originator. This is one of the reasons why you need a valid `From:` address.

The number `661D12C0CD` in this example is the queue-ID of the remote system. Use that when looking through the logs (or talking to the postmaster) on the recipient side.

Answer (score 5):

> Should I change my hostname on the machine to mysubdomain.mydomain.com?

Normally, SPAM filter take apart of the domain name, the IP originating the spam (in some cases even the entire ip block or the ASN completly, check [UCEPROTECT](http://www.uceprotect.net/en/index.php) and [Whatsmyip.com](http://whatismyipaddress.com/blacklist-check) blacklist check)

> What other things do I have to do with the DNS to prevent my email from going into the spam folder?

This has been said several times already but, **do not send SPAM**, that should be the first method. After that, use SSL/TLS for all the connections from/to the server. Suspend accounts that use your server to send SPAM. Don't configure your server as Open Relay. Harden your server against hackers. Etc. Etc. There is just too many tools and method you can employ to do this that it will not end.

> I just updated the PTR to the main domain name. How can I diagnose why my server's mail isn't reaching its destination?

Are you sure that your ISP allows you to send E-mails? Have you configured your server ports correctly? Is the server able to mail itself? Is difficult to diagnose since there are just too many things could have go wrong from local, to middle to end point and without logs, pings, test and more test is impossible to know. If you want you can check http://whatismyipaddress.com/blacklist-check and input your server IP. If it's listed is probable that that could be the reason you don't receive emails from the server, if it's not listed then you must provide more information and test that you have done.

Resources:

- [How to send emails and avoid them being classified as spam](https://serverfault.com/questions/48428/how-to-send-emails-and-avoid-them-being-classified-as-spam) (thanks to [minopret](https://superuser.com/users/115912/minopret))
- [Best Practices for preventing you from looking like a spammer](https://serverfault.com/q/41693/180142)

Answer (score 2):

[MX Toolbox](http://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx) is your friend. Do a `mx:mysubdomain.mydomain.com`, `blacklist:mysubdomain.mydomain.com`, and `ptr:mysubdomain.mydomain.com` search using their supertool to diagnose mail issues.

AOL, JUNO, and YAHOO (maybe more, but those for sure) require valid PTR records from the sending email server in order for mail to be delivered to their users. I have noticed GMAIL does not require a PTR record but it does look for an MX record of the host.

Answer (score 1):

Forward and reverse dns entry must be the same **and** the forward dns entry has to be the mx entry for your domain. Normally you could add/change the forward dns entry and the mx entry on a web interface of your domain provider. The reverse dns entry you have to set up on the web interface of your host provider. If you can´t set this up on the web interface please talk to your host provider most of them will do this for you.

And you have to set up (add) the following files correctly:

*/etc/hosts*

```
 X.X.X.X myhostname.mydomain.com myhostname
```

*/etc/hostname*

```
 myhostname
```

*/etc/mailname*

```
myhostname.mydomain.com
```

These settings are no guaranty that other mail servers will declare your emails as spam but it reduce it dramatically.

Answer (score 0):

For me, these 2 points were enough to pass through yahoo's, and google's spam filter:

1. Make sure the computer sending the email has a Reverse PTR record
2. Configure DomainKeys Identified Mail in your DNS and code

You can read about it in this nice little article, written by Jeff Atwood
https://blog.codinghorror.com/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code/